# Cordova : what kind of cordova plugins should be removed in release time?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, cordova-plugins, sencha-cmd, cordova-cli

i'm working in sencha touch application with cordova. i plan to make release apk for android.

Could any one explain me which kind of plugins we don't use with release apk ?

i.e i'm using these plugins in my project,

- com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin 2.4.0 "PushPlugin"
- com.toluhta.immersify 0.1.0 "Immersify"
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1-dev "InAppBrowser"
- de.mobilino.phonegap.AndroidLicensePlugin 1.0.0 "AndroidLicensePlugin"
- org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.4 "Camera"
- org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console"
- org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
- org.apache.cordova.file 1.3.2 "File"
- org.apache.cordova.file-transfer 0.4.8 "File Transfer"
- org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.12 "Geolocation"
- org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.15 "Network Information"
- org.jshybugger.cordova 4.5.8 "jsHybugger"

please tell any plugin i need to remove before release ?

Comment: What is making you think of removing any on the listed plugin?

Comment: i think i need to remove debugging plugin when i move for release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe `org.apache.cordova.console` that is making console.log accessible and is not mandatory for release IMO.

Otherwise, if you add a plugin and don't need it for release, just remove it for debug also ;)

**Extra info**

Be carefull, you are using deprecated plugins : `org.apache.cordova...` .
Shall be `cordova-plugin-..`

Comment: ya thank man. but when i install cordova plugin its display like org.apache.cordova

Comment: because you install it with a wrong command and your are installing in fact a deprecated package.
try to remove it : cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova....
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-..

Exemple : cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: thanks man. i got a link for updated plugins link. https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html